# "How to Fix" logic in C# factorial Calculation's

Tags: c#

I need to write a factorisation calculator with recursion, for the purpose of learning nLog and how to build custom exceptions.

I have tried a few different implementations in visual studio 2019 CE with "if" and "for" loops but I don't really know what I'm doing.

```
   public static int Factorial(int input)
        {


            try
                {
                // create a count for step of recursion

                int factorCount = 0;
                int sqrt = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(input));

              for (int step=1; step<=sqrt;step++)
                {
                    if(input % step == 0) {

                        //incress the current step of recursion by one 
                        factorCount++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Calculator.Factorial:Calculating",step);

                    }
                        Console.WriteLine(input);
              }
```

The current code is throwing up a
 "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException." and that it is getting till at lest "Console.WriteLine("Calculator.Factorial:Calculating",step); "
before crashing.

Comment: Are you trying to do factorial with 2 ways (recursion and looping)? I suggest you to do it using looping first since It's easier.

Comment: I'm meant to be using recursion for the factorisation but a lot of the examples use looping I'm not exactly sure of the difference and thought they both played into each other

Comment: I don't see any recursion in your code. And I'm not sure if the factorial I know is the same with yours.

Comment: What value you have in input ?

Comment: the number that is being factorised goes into the input value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't use recursion in your code at all. recursion means a function call itself within itself. in factorial you for n! you have to calculate (n-1)! till n-1 =1. try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static int Fact(int n)
        {
            if (n <= 1)
                return 1;
            return n * Fact(n - 1);
        }

        static int Factorial(int n)
        {
            if (n <= 1)
                return 1;
            int result = 1;
            for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            {
                result = result * i;
            }
            return result;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a Number to find factorial: ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int r = Fact(n);
            Console.WriteLine(n.ToString() + "! = " + r.ToString());

            Console.Write("Enter a Number to find factorial: ");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            r = Factorial(n);
            Console.WriteLine(n.ToString() + "! = " + r.ToString());           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ohh that makes a lot more sense thank you so much